# Ссылка с заглушкой

Tags: html, html5

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку с заглушкой которая находится, к примеру в середине страницы, не перебрасывало на самый верх страницы? Чтобы положение на странице оставалось на том месте.

```css
.middle {
  margin-top: 400px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="middle">
  <li><a href="#">Почтовые коробки оригинальные</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Почтовые коробки бурые</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Почтовые коробки бурые с бланком</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Веришь или нет но я задавался этим вопросом 15 минут назад;)

Comment: А зачем тогда ссылка вообще нужна?

Comment: @andreymal кнопочки делать:)

Comment: @midia у кнопочек свой тег есть :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавить атрибут "onclick"

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">текст</a>
```

```css
.middle {
  margin-top: 400px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="middle">
  <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Почтовые коробки оригинальные</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Почтовые коробки бурые</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Почтовые коробки бурые с бланком</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Убрать атрибут `href`, если `href` нужен, то можно добавить `onclick="return false;"`.

Ссылка обычно и создается чтобы быть ссылкой или якорем или на начальном этапе разработке когда это пока не имеет значение.

Если нужно что то вроде кнопки на выполнение события то необязательно это делать тегом `a`, можно взять тег `span` например и добавить ему стили

```css
.middle {
  margin-top: 400px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="middle">
  <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Почтовые коробки оригинальные</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Почтовые коробки бурые</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Почтовые коробки бурые с бланком</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно изменить значение атрибута `href="#!`

```css
.middle {
  margin-top: 400px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="middle">
  <li><a href="#!" onclick="return false;">Почтовые коробки оригинальные</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!" onclick="return false;">Почтовые коробки бурые</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!" onclick="return false;">Почтовые коробки бурые с бланком</a></li>
</ul>
```